# Use of CreateProcess on WinCE6

Tags: windows-ce

I'm trying to launch a process from my program, namely cmd.exe.
Doc says I have to use CreateProcess, and below is how I use it :

CreateProcess((LPCWSTR) "\Windows\cmd.exe", (LPCWSTR) "", 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
dw = GetLastError();
printf("%u \n", dw);

The path is the one displayed by the target (on the target, I found a shortcut to cmd.exe which states it resides in \windows.

The error is always the same (2), regardless of how I write the path. Apparently, the error code for (2) is Invalid_Path.

Thanks for having read,
GQ

Answer (score 1):

You are passing an incorrect string to create process. Just casting a byte-oriented string to LPCWSTR doesn't fix the problem that it is incorrect data - you really have to use a Unicode string, which you can spell as

```
CreateProcess(L"\\Windows\\cmd.exe", NULL, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`TEXT()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374074%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) macro.

Comment: Hi,It doesn't seem to make any difference

Comment: There were more mistakes: you should escape backslashes, and the command line should be writable or NULL. OTOH: are you certain that \windows\cmd.exe actually exists in your CE build?

Comment: The TCHAR macro _T would also work for getting the text to the proper format.

Answer (score 0):

The path is incorrect. Use double backslash.

```
CreateProcess(TEXT("\\Windows\\cmd.exe"), TEXT(""), 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, the last parameter cannot be `NULL`. It must be a pointer to `PROCESS_INFORMATION` structure. For details, see the following link

[MSDN link for Creating Process in Windows CE 6.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee482760%28v=winembedded.60%29.aspx)